# Why is Microsoft AspNetCore App showing twice in Dependencies

Tags: asp.net-core

Creat a new .net core web api project

View Dependencies

See picture below.

Why is Microsoft.AspNetCore.App required twice?
It is in the default csproj:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.0.2105168" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

And also under SDK.

I don't understand the reason for this, very confusing. If I remove it from csproj and do a clean and run, application runs

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` is both a dependency of your application (the NuGet node) as well as a dependency of the SDK you're using. You can find the SDK at the top of your project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

The Web SDK references the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` package in one of its MSBuild target files. You can find the SDK targets in the SDK installation folder: `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\<version>\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web\Sdk`

Starting from .NET Core 3.0, these references will change and you can reference the framework using a `<FrameworkReference>` element rather than a `<PackageReference>` element to avoid ambiguity. See the following GitHub issues for more info:

- https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/325
- https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3612

Comment: thank you, that clears it up. I presume it builds successfully, even when I remove from csproj, as the sdk references it in a target file as you said

Comment: The current (for version 2.2) best practice is to include `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` without a version number in your project file.